# Apply some changes to enable FinishEditButton in XPM

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager, gui-extensions

I'm developing an extension in XPM which changes the funcionality to the Component Presentations in a Page. 
I would like to enable the FinishEditButton when I change some parameters in my extension.
For example, in CME I solved this problem changing the title of the Page in order to enable the Save/SaveAndClose/SaveAndNew buttons.

Is it possible to do something similar in XPM? Is there any event/way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Problably this solution it's not the better solution... but while I find a "elegant" way, it works for me.
We can lie to the page and "tell him" that a component has changed with the next code (it works with a Component Presentation selected):

```
var itemSelected = $models.getItem($display.getView().properties.selectionInfo.component);
itemSelected.setChanged("");
```

This trigger an event and the buttons "SaveAll" and "FinishEditing" are now enabled.

Hope it helps.